# Passing different number of arguments into function

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def save(self, text, *index): 
    file.write(text + '\nResults:\n')
    if index == (): index = (range(len(self.drinkList)))
    for x in index:
        for y in self.drinkList[x].ing:
            file.write('min: ' + str(y.min) + ' max: ' + str(y.max) + ' value: ' + str(y.perc) + '\n')
        file.write('\n\n')
    file.write('\nPopulation fitness: ' + str(self.calculatePopulationFitness()) + '\n\n----------------------------------------------\n\n')
```

Now, when I pass one argument as an index the function works as it is supposed to, but when I pass a tuple of 2 indices I get an TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple. What should I change?

Comment: Can you show how you're calling that function?

Comment: self.save('Resulted in ' , (index1, index2))
self.save('Resulted in ' , index)
The first call gives an error, when I pass it without making it a tuple the resulting file is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `save(self, text, *index)` syntax means that [`index` is itself a
tuple](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) with all the arguments passed to `save` after the `text` one.

So, for instance, if you have in your code:

```
myobject.save("sample text", 1, 2, 3)
```

then `index` will be the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` and the `for x in
index` will correctly loop over values `1`, `2`, `3`.

On the other hand, if you haveL

```
myobject.save("sample text", (1,2))
```

then `index` will be the 1-element tuple `((1,2),)` and the `x` in the
loop will get the value `(1,2)`, hence the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what parameters you were actually trying to pass. I presume you called something to the effect of:

```
object.save("hello world", (3, 4, 5))
```

When you use the * operator, you do not need to pass the variable number of arguments as a tuple. Instead, everything that you pass after the fixed arguments is wrapped into a list. Therefore, in this case, the variable `index` refers to `[(3, 4, 5)]`, not `[3, 4, 5]`.

You should call the function `save` like this instead:

```
object.save("hello world", 3, 4, 5)
```

The variable `index` now refers to `[3, 4, 5]`.

If, for some reason, you wanted to still pass a tuple, simply change your function definition to:

```
def save(self, text, index): # Observe the lack of '*'
```

Comment: Note that if you wish to continue to allow passing just one argument, this alternate could be something like `def save(self, text, index=())`.

Answer (score 1):

With the *index definition, you have to call the function as `save(self, text, index1, index2)`, and `index` will be a tuple, `(index1, index2)`. If you are passing a tuple to `save` after the argument, `text`, you can leave the `*` out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your method with a tuple of indices like

```
x.save("ababs",(0,1))
```

Just call it with the indices one after another as if they were distinct paramaters to the method

```
x.save("ababs",0,1)
```